# GitHub social media image is not refreshed on update

Tags: facebook, github, share, repository-design

I've changed the social media image of my GitHub repository, but when I try to share it in facebook and it displays the old image as I've never updated it in the first place. The image can be updated by going to [`your repo`](https://github.com/dvdvideo1234/TrackAssemblyTool) `->` `Settings` `->` `Social preview`. I dowloaded the template and used it to create an image, but did not remove the red bars on the sides. When I shared it looked like crap, so I removed the red bars and made them white. Now my phone does not want to display the new image when I share it on facebook.

Is this a browser related cache issue or simply the GitHub feature does not work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Facebook caches OG meta data, use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to re-scrape your URL.

Comment: FB, Twitter, and Linkedin links to re-scrape URLs: https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/215769058-Update-social-media-preview-cards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved when I made an URL `re-scrape` as `@04FS` suggested. I had to open the facebook page with a regular browser, not the dedicated app, follow the link he provided and paste the URL in there. In the option `Time Scraped` was set to yesterday at `11:32`, which means that FB caches internally the URL result. After hitting the button `Scrape Again`, the social media picture appeared correctly without the red borders.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `?anything` to link of repository.

Example : https://github.com/ZakariaMahmoud/image-generator/?anything

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Twitter. It was enough logging out and logging in again.

Comment: I have it with Twitter too. Sadly logging out and back in didn't fix it.